# Formula to take two columns' unique values and paste them into one

Tags: excel

I know how to copy one column, then the other, and paste them into a column then remove duplicates.  But I want one formula that does this.  Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible and has been asked and answered on this forum many times.  The formula would need to be an array formula and it is very long and convoluted.  If your dataset is large it will crash excel.  vba would be the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical *3 column formula* that you can adapt to your needs:

With data in **A1** through **C10**, in **D1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **D2** enter the array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$10,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$1:$C$10)=0,ROW($A$1:$C$10)+(COLUMN($A$1:$C$10)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$1:$C$10)=0,ROW($A$1:$C$10)+(COLUMN($A$1:$C$10)*0.01)),1),1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

From:

[Coderre Formula](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/extract-unique-data-from-table/1ba1796a-c647-e011-9575-d8d385dcbb12)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that works on the two columns but sorts it in a different order.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B))),0)),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This formula must be entered in the second row.  If you want your list to start in the first row then in the first cell put: `=A1` then put the above formula in the second row, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy/drag down.

[image]